# Why no nominalization in「この本を読んでみてはどうですか。」?

Tags: nuances

In

> **この本を読んでみては**どうですか。
>
> How about you read this book.

Why is 「この本を読んでみて」not nominalized? As in:

> **この本を読んでみるのは**どうですか。